# Ошибки в программе, помогите пожалуйста исправить

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал троллинг-взлом казино на путхоне, но в конце "взлома" оно выдает много ошибок, помогите плиз исправить
Ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\йцу\Documents\PythonProjects\hack_casino_vulkan.py", line 44, in <module>
    hacker()
  File "C:\Users\йцу\Documents\PythonProjects\hack_casino_vulkan.py", line 40, in hacker
    vivod()
  File "C:\Users\йцу\Documents\PythonProjects\hack_casino_vulkan.py", line 16, in vivod
    vivi=int(input('Казино Вулкан успешно взломано!\nБыло выкачано:',randint(2456, 846368),'\nЖелаете вывести деньги? 1-ДА, 0-НЕТ, 2-Попробовать еще раз(возможно выкачать больше'))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 3
```

Исходник:

```
from time import sleep
import time
import random
import sys
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
from random import randint
import os
import webbrowser 


init(convert=True)

ggg=(input('Вас приветствует программа hack casino vulkan!\nНапишите 1 чтобы начать, 0 чтобы пойти пойти нафиг\n'))

def vivod():
        vivi=int(input('Казино Вулкан успешно взломано!\nБыло выкачано:',randint(2456, 846368),'\nЖелаете вывести деньги? 1-ДА, 0-НЕТ, 2-Попробовать еще раз(возможно выкачать больше'))

        if vivi=='1':
            print(Back.RED + 'Генерация прокси....')
            time.sleep(randint(32, 57))
            print(Back.RED + 'Создание ссылки....')
            time.sleep(randint(35, 111))
            print(Back.RED + 'Настройка страницы....')
            time.sleep(randint(50, 112))
            print(Back.BLUE + 'Завершение....')
            time.sleep(randint(32, 57))
            print(Back.BLUE + 'Открытие....')
            time.sleep(randint(3, 13))
            webbrowser.open('https://hack.bitrix24.site', new=0)
        if vivi=='2':
            print(Back.BLUE + 'Перезапуск...')
            time.sleep(randint(3, 6))
            os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv) 
        else:
            print(Back.BLUE + 'До встречи!')
            time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit()

def hacker():
    print(Back.GREEN + 'Загрузка.....\n')
    time.sleep(randint(9, 30))
    print(Back.GREEN + 'Запуск.....\n')
    time.sleep(randint(12, 45))
    print(Back.BLUE + 'ВЗЛОМ КАЗИНО ВУЛКАН ЗАВЕРШЕН НА 1 %')
    time.sleep(randint(3, 7))
    print(Back.BLUE + 'ВЗЛОМ КАЗИНО ВУЛКАН ЗАВЕРШЕН НА',randint(2,5),'%')
    time.sleep(randint(15, 60))
    print(Back.BLUE + 'ВЗЛОМ КАЗИНО ВУЛКАН ЗАВЕРШЕН НА',randint(6,10),'%')
    time.sleep(randint(12, 45))
    print(Back.BLUE + 'ВЗЛОМ КАЗИНО ВУЛКАН ЗАВЕРШЕН НА',randint(11,17),'%')
    time.sleep(randint(34, 65))
    print(Back.BLUE + 'ВЗЛОМ КАЗИНО ВУЛКАН ЗАВЕРШЕН НА',randint(18,49),'%')
    time.sleep(randint(38, 80))
    print(Back.BLUE + 'ВЗЛОМ КАЗИНО ВУЛКАН ЗАВЕРШЕН НА',randint(50,67),'%')
    time.sleep(randint(45, 80))
    print(Back.BLUE + 'ВЗЛОМ КАЗИНО ВУЛКАН ЗАВЕРШЕН НА',randint(68,75),'%')
    time.sleep(randint(60, 90))
    print(Back.BLUE + 'ВЗЛОМ КАЗИНО ВУЛКАН ЗАВЕРШЕН НА',randint(76,84),'%')
    time.sleep(randint(73, 120))
    print(Back.BLUE + 'ВЗЛОМ КАЗИНО ВУЛКАН ЗАВЕРШЕН НА',randint(85,92),'%')
    time.sleep(randint(78, 125))
    print(Back.BLUE + 'ВЗЛОМ КАЗИНО ВУЛКАН ЗАВЕРШЕН НА',randint(93,97),'%')
    time.sleep(randint(83, 129))
    print(Back.BLUE + 'ВЗЛОМ КАЗИНО ВУЛКАН ЗАВЕРШЕН НА 100 %')
    time.sleep(randint(3, 8))
    vivod()


if ggg=='1':
    hacker()
else:
    print(Back.BLUE + 'Вы идете нафиг...')
    time.sleep(3)
    print(Back.RED + 'Вы пришли нафиг! Досвидания!')
    time.sleep(3)
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Вы передали недостаточное число аргументов

Comment: @hedgehogues Наоборот - избыточное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего исправить так:

```
print('Казино Вулкан успешно взломано!\nБыло выкачано:',randint(2456, 846368),'\nЖелаете вывести деньги? 1-ДА, 0-НЕТ, 2-Попробовать еще раз(возможно выкачать больше')
vivi=int(input())
```

У вас `input` ругается, что он может принимать только один аргумент, а вы передали ему три.